# MongoDb get distinct items after grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongodb with the following collection sample

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5703750ca9c436386c4814c9"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(17),
    "activitytype_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2015-10-03T03:52:03.000Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5703750ca9c436386c4814ca"),
    "s_id" : NumberLong(132919),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(17),
    "activitytype_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2016-03-18T17:13:43.000Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5703750ca9c436386c4814cb"),
    "s_id" : NumberLong(215283),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(17),
    "activitytype_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2015-10-03T04:12:33.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5703750ca9c436386c4814cc"),
    "s_id" : NumberLong(360888),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(17),
    "activitytype_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2015-10-03T04:12:41.000Z")
}
```

This is my aggregation pipeline

```js
db.activitylogs.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { 
            user_id: "$user_id",
            activitytype_id: "$activitytype_id" 
        }, 
        activity_log_docs: {
            $addToSet: { 
                s_id: "$s_id", 
                friend_id: "$friend_id",                           
                playlist_id: "$playlist_id",
                created_date:"$created_date"
            }
        }              
    }},   
])
```

I need to get distinct `s_id` in  `activity_log_docs`.

here is a screenshot for the result,
[screen shot for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCRgD.png)

i need to avoid duplicated s_id in activity_log_docs array, so i will get distinct s_id

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Since you are "grouping" on certain keys then this makes the other document content really "invalid", since of course there are "multiple values" for those other keys. Use operators like [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to get "one" of the values per key instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do :

```
db.activitylogs.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { 
            user_id: "$user_id",
            activitytype_id: "$activitytype_id" ,
            s_id:"$s_id"
        }, 
        friend_id: {$first:"$friend_id"}}},
        playlist_id: {$first:"$playlist_id"}}},
        created_date: {$first:"$created_date"}}},
    { $group: {
        _id: { 
            user_id: "$_id.user_id",
            activitytype_id: "$_id.activitytype_id" 
        }, 
        activity_log_docs: {
            $addToSet: { 
                s_id: "$_id.s_id", 
                friend_id: "$friend_id",                           
                playlist_id: "$playlist_id",
                created_date:"$created_date"
            }
        }              
    }},   
])
```

But please double check your own field's name.